# shift array elements to left in java

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, shift

I am writing the SDES cipher in java, getting to the stage where I am shifting two arrays of length 5 one space to the left, this works fine for p10kleft to become shiftp10kleft, but when I apply the same code to p10kright to become shiftp10kright it adds a random 1 at the end instead of shifting the first 0 to become the last bit.

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
package ciphers;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SDESNew {

    public static void main(String []arg)throws Exception
    {
        int[] k = {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0};
        int[] P10 = {3,5,2,7,4,10,1,9,8,6};
        int[] P8 = {6,3,7,4,8,5,10,9};
        int[] P4 = {2,4,3,1};
        int[] IP = {2,6,3,1,4,8,5,7};
        int[] EP = {4,1,2,3,2,3,4,1};
        int S0[][] = {
                        {1,0,3,2},
                        {3,2,1,0},
                        {0,2,1,3},
                        {3,1,3,2}
                    };

        int S1[][] = {
                        {0,1,2,3},
                        {2,0,1,3},
                        {3,0,1,2},
                        {2,1,0,3}
                    };

        //Arrays that we have to calculate
        int p10k[]=new int[10]; //Create p10(k) array
        int[] p10kleft = new int[5];
        int[] p10kright = new int[5];
        int[] shiftp10kleft = new int[5];
        int[] shiftp10kright = new int[5];



        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Value from array P10: " +P10[i]);                           //Printing values from array P10
            System.out.println("Array position to be used in array k: "     +(P10[i]-1)); //Array position begins at 0 so subtracting 1 from P10 position so array begins at 0
            System.out.println(k[P10[i]-1]); //Printing values in array positions
            p10k[i]=k[P10[i]-1]; //Putting array values in p10k array
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("P10k: " +Arrays.toString(p10k)); //Printing out all values in p10k array

         System.arraycopy(p10k, 0, p10kleft, 0, p10kleft.length);
         System.arraycopy(p10k, p10kleft.length, p10kright, 0, p10kright.length);

         System.out.println("Left: " +Arrays.toString(p10kleft));
         System.out.println("Right: " +Arrays.toString(p10kright));



        // System.arraycopy(p10kleft, 1, shiftp10kleft, 0, p10kleft.length - 1);

         int n = p10kleft.length;
         shiftp10kleft = p10kleft;
         int i = 0;
         if (n>0)
         {
             for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
             {
                 p10kleft[i]=p10kleft[i+1];
             }
         }
         p10kleft[i] = shiftp10kleft[i];


         System.out.println("Shift Left: " +Arrays.toString(shiftp10kleft));




         n  = p10kright.length;
         shiftp10kright = p10kright;
         i = 0;
         if (n>0)
         {
             for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
             {
                 p10kright[i]=p10kright[i+1];
             }
         }
         p10kright[i] = shiftp10kright[i];


         System.out.println("Shift Right: " +Arrays.toString(shiftp10kright));


        } 

        }
```

HERE IS THE CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
Value from array P10: 3
Array position to be used in array k: 2
1

Value from array P10: 5
Array position to be used in array k: 4
0

Value from array P10: 2
Array position to be used in array k: 1
1

Value from array P10: 7
Array position to be used in array k: 6
1

Value from array P10: 4
Array position to be used in array k: 3
1

Value from array P10: 10
Array position to be used in array k: 9
0

Value from array P10: 1
Array position to be used in array k: 0
1

Value from array P10: 9
Array position to be used in array k: 8
0

Value from array P10: 8
Array position to be used in array k: 7
0

Value from array P10: 6
Array position to be used in array k: 5
1

P10k: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

Left: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

Right: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

Shift Left: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Shift Right: [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

---

I need Shift Right to correctly output [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

Comment: Why are you using arrays? This seems like a very C++-y way of doing things, which is not as easy as it might look to port to Java. You could much more easily go either the C-y way and use bitwise operations on e.g. `long`, or go the Java-y way and wrap them in their own interface.

Comment: I prefer this method, but Im just confused as to why the same code I used to generate p10kleft doesn't work in the same way to generate p10kright

Comment: It looks to me like `p10kleft[i] = shiftp10kleft[i];` should instead read `p10kleft[i] = shiftp10kleft[0];`. I'm not entirely clear on what your code does, so I could be wrong. In either case, consider using at least `Arrays.copyOfRange()` instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: shiftp10kleft works fine, it is correctly shifting each element of the p10kleft array to the left. I am trying to do the same to p10kright but it is not working

Comment: Yes, but you seem to be assigning the same value (the last value in the array) back to itself with that line. It looks like what you meant to do was assign the old 0th element to the new last element.

Comment: tried it just now, I changed p10kleft[i] = shiftp10kleft[i]; to p10kleft[i] = shiftp10kleft[0]; and p10kright[i] = shiftp10kright[i]; to p10kright[i] = shiftp10kright[0];

Unfortunately this was unsuccessful, the output given was


Left: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

Right: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

Shift Left: [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

Shift Right: [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]

Comment: I meant that as a design change. `p10kright` and `shiftp10kright` point to the same array, what you want to do is store the first value in a primitive BEFORE the loop (`first = shiftp10kright[0];`) and then put it in the last element AFTER it: `p10kright[i] = first;`. Side note: having two variables point to the same array is pointless.

Comment: Success! Thank you very much that worked perfectly. There's one other thing, do you know what I would have to change within the for loop to make the shift be 3 spaces to the left instead of 1? Its for the next stage

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments, storing the first value in a primitive before going in the loop:

```
     int n = p10kleft.length;
     shiftp10kleft = p10kleft;
     int i = 0;
     int first = p10kleft[i];
     if (n>0)
     {
         for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
         {
             p10kleft[i]=p10kleft[i+1];
         }
     }
     p10kleft[i] = first;
```

Regarding your other question, repeating this operation 3 times is the obvious (and not particularly smart, or efficient way) to do it:

```
for(int shiftCounter = 0; shiftCounter < 3; shiftCounter++) {
     int n = p10kleft.length;
     ...
     p10kleft[i] = first;
}
```

In any case there are a number of better ways of doing this, as I already suggested. If you're dead set on arrays, however, you could at least make use of `System.arraycopy`. A simplistic example would be:

```
static int[] shiftLeft(int[] arr, int shift) {
    int[] tmp = new int[arr.length];
    System.arraycopy(arr, shift, tmp, 0, arr.length-shift);
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, tmp, arr.length-shift, shift);
    return tmp;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
p10kleft = shiftLeft(p10kleft, 1); // shift once
p10kleft = shiftLeft(p10kleft, 3); // shift 3 times
```

EDIT: fix parameter order in `arraycopy`.